# PHP - Induvidual elements to Uppercase

Tags: php

I am working through the Coderbyte challenges as I am teaching myself some PHP.

I have been working through the below challenge (link below)

[Coderbyte Challenge](http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/Editor.php?ct=Letter%20Changes&lan=PHP)

I have got the to below and I a bit confused as it now capitalises each letter of the array rather than the letters selected in the 'if statement'.

I am eager to learn and dont just simply want an answer without an explanation. If you could tell me where I am going wrong and if I am doing things in a long winded approach.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php 

function LetterChanges($str) {  

// code goes here
$str = strtolower($str);
$strArray = str_split($str);

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){

  ++$strArray[$i];

 if($strArray[$i] == "aa"){
   $strArray[$i] = "A";
 }
 elseif($strArray[$i] == "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"){
   $strArray[$i] = strtoupper($strArray[$i]);
 }

 }

 return implode ($strArray); 

 }

 // keep this function call here  
 // to see how to enter arguments in PHP scroll down
 echo LetterChanges(fgets(fopen('php://stdin', 'r')));  

 ?>
```

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){

        if(ord($strArray[$i]) >= 97 && ord($strArray[$i]) <= 122)
            ++$strArray[$i];

        if($strArray[$i] == "aa"){
            $strArray[$i] = "a";
        }
        if(in_array($strArray[$i], array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"))) {
            $strArray[$i] = strtoupper($strArray[$i]);
        }

    }`

Comment: provide sample string you want to convert

Comment: this is clearly wrong >> if($strArray[$i] == "aa")
, maybe you meant
 if($strArray[$i] == "a" && $strArray[$i+1]=="a"){
unset($strArray[$i]);
++$i;
$strArray[$i]='A';
}

Comment: or maybe if($strArray[$i]=='a' && ($strArray[$i+1]++)=='a'){ unset($strArray[$i]); ++$i; $strArray[$i]='A'; ++$i;continue;}

Comment: Explanation for the all capitalized effect: `$strArray[$i] == "e" || "i" ||...` is always true. you cannot group several check values with ` || ` ...every element is interpreted as its own statement, `"i"`, a non-empty string, has a truthy value. You would need to make the comparison for every letter `$strArray[$i] == "e" || $strArray[$i] == "i" || ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
function LetterChanges($str){
    $arr = array();
    $strlen = strlen( $str );
    for( $i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++ ) {
        $char = substr( $str, $i, 1 );
        ++$char;

        if($char == "a" || $char == "e" || $char== "i" || $char== "o" || $char== "u"){
            $char = strtoupper($char);
        }
        if($char == "aa"){
            $char = 'A';  //When we increase Z it becomes aa so we changed it to A 
        }
        $arr[] = $char;
    }
    //print_r($arr);
    echo implode("",$arr);
}

LetterChanges('hello*3');
```

**Explanation**

In `for` loop get each character separately in an array then increase it by one then in that increased character we check for vowels if they present then we change them uppercase and again change that array to simple string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems to do the job. Good to know i was at least heading in the right direction.

Comment: @Tomaff Yes you was almost there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increment a character using  like this => "++$strArray[$i];"
For this you have to first get the ascii value of that character in php you could get ascii value of character using ord() function then increment that ascii value by one and then conver it back into character using chr() function.

Here is full solution to your problem:

```
function LetterChanges($str) {  

// code goes here
$str = strtolower($str);
$strarray = str_split($str);
$newarray = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($strarray); $i++) {
  if(ord($strarray[$i])>=97 && ord($strarray)<=122) {
      $newarray[$i] = chr(ord($strarray[$i])+1);
  } else {
      $newarray[$i] = $strarray[$i];
}
if($newarray[$i]=='a' || $newarray[$i]=='e' || $newarray[$i]=='i' || $newarray[$i]=='o' || $newarray[$i]=='u') {
    $newarray[$i] = strtoupper($newarray[$i]);
}
}

$str = implode('',$newarray);

return $str;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good to see the different approaches to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It will work

```
<?php 

 function LetterChanges($str) {  

 $strlen = strlen( $str );

 $out = '';
 for($i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++) {
    $char = substr($str,$i,1);
  if(!is_numeric($char)) {
        $nextChar = ++$char;    
        if (strlen($nextChar) > 1) { // if you go beyond z or Z reset to a or A
            $nextChar = $next_ch[0];
        }
    if(in_array($char,array('a','e','i','o','u'))) {
        $nextChar = strtoupper($nextChar);
    }
  }
  else {
    $nextChar = $char;
  }

  $out .= $nextChar;

}
$str = $out;


// code goes here
return $str; 

}

// keep this function call here  
// to see how to enter arguments in PHP scroll down
echo LetterChanges(fgets(fopen('php://stdin', 'r')));  

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good to see the different approaches to the same problem.